# Go does not recognize a func as a valid interface

Tags: go, interface

I have the func

```
func(context.Context, *domain.Scorecard) (*domain.Scorecard, error)
```

And i want pass this as a param that receive a interface

```
warehouse interface {
   Get(context.Context, *domain.Scorecard) (*domain.Scorecard, error)
}
```

Ex:

```
warehouseMock := 
usecase.WithScenarioFinder(
  func(player *domain.Player) (*domain.Scenario, error) {
          return nil,nil
)
```

The traditional form is create a struct that have the method Get, but i have curiosity if exist the way to tell "hey, that is a simple func, is the same firm (with no name), accept it"

Comment: Yes, if you define a named func type and define a method on it that calls the func. See https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#HandlerFunc

Comment: Without a defining a method, no. Interfaces define *methods*, not *functions*, so they can *only* be satisfied by a method with the given name and signature.

Comment: No there is no way to say *"hey, that is a simple func, is the same firm (with no name), accept it"* with a func whose type has no name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Functions do not implement interfaces with only a single method of that same signature. See [this Go issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/21670) for a discussion on the topic.

Create an adaptor type to convert a function to an interface:

```
type WarehouseFunc func(context.Context, *domain.Scorecard) (*domain.Scorecard, error)

func (f WarehouseFunc) Get(c context.Context, d *domain.Scorecard) (*domain.Scorecard, error) {
   return f(c, d)
}
```

Convert an anonymous function to an interface like this:

```
itf = WarehouseFunc(func(c context.Context, d *domain.Scorecard) (*domain.Scorecard, error) {
    return nil, nil
})
```